# How to calculate the meeting time of two moving objects with different angles

Tags: javascript, algorithm, physics, collision

There are two objects moving with different angles. What I'm trying to do is to calculate the meeting time of the objects. The return type is a time value, or "infinite" in the case that these objects will never meet.

Now, I'm using a simulation function to solve this problem. In simulation function, system simulates the future of the movement for a time period and checks the objects' current positions. If there is a meet in any time, function returns the time which elapsed until meeting, or "infinite" if meeting didnt occur for a time period, let's say 18s

If I could find a Physics formula or a CS algorithm then I could maybe implement it. I wonder if there is a straightforward algorithm that can calculate the meeting time of two moving objects with different angles?

Comment: What if they didn't meet? I think the easier solution is to have two lines at different angles (and positions) and then equate the position of their point of intersection.

Comment: This is in 2 dimensions only? Not in 3 dimensions? No gravity?

Comment: Well friends, actually objects have different speeds but I didn't include it because it makes things more complicated. Two dimensions and no grav.

Comment: @ D. Pardal Intersection of lines does not mean object collision

Comment: @MBo: Intersection is where they would colide if they are there at the same time. So it's a two step problem: 1. Where do the trajectory lines intersect? 2. Are the objects there at the "same" time? It is a very simple problem.

Comment: After your explanation, I convinced that this is a very simple problem If I can find the intersection point of lines and time is very important because I dont want to use simulation. So there are time and distance variables which are unknown. All I have is angle of objects. (I dont include the speed)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You only have angles, and no speed? That is not possible. You cannot move something at an indeterminate speed (unless you're talking about quantum mechanics, of course).

Comment: Well I have speed but not different speeds. Therefore, the speed of objects does not matter as long as they are same. it is 5m/s or 50 m/s. This doesn't change the intersection point but the time

Comment: Oke, the speed is the same. In that case you need the starting points and the intersection of the two trajectory lines. Then calculate, using the Pythagorean theorem, the distance between both starting points and the intersection point. If the two distances are very close then the two objects must have collided, since they would have take the same amount of time to travel to the intersection point.

Comment: Are you comfortable with vectors?

Comment: Not at all. In fact, simulation function looks like the most efficient way to calculate this. For the reason that the function is tracking every movement of objectz, we can say that the function is working with vectorz

Answer (score 0):

Build formula for position of every object depending on time P1(t), P2(t).
Find coordinate difference and formula for distance depending on time `Distance(t) = Sqrt(P1)`.
Solve for `Distance(t) < sum of object radii`, find unknown t (time)